# Is there a way to add the latest git log to a commit?

Tags: git

I recently took over a project that is severely lacking in documentation, with no changelogs at all and thus no version history. However, it does appear that the git log is decently maintained. Due to this, I'm temporarily bundling the git log in the release as a stop-gap measure until I figure out a more permanent solution.

The problem is that when I write the git log to a file in the repository, it doesn't contain the latest commit message as the commit hasn't been made yet. That is to say, I have to run `git log > commit_log.rtf` before making the commit, and as a result, the newest commit is not present in the log file which is committed. Is there a way to circumvent this issue that doesn't involve two commits, with the second one used solely to update the singular log file?

Thanks,

Kai

Comment: The short answer is no: the identity of a commit depends exquisitely upon all of the data *in* the commit, so such a commit would depend on itself, making it impossible to make. But if the content of `commit_log.rtf` is solely mechanically generated, it should not be _in_ Git in the first place: just build it from the commit hash again if you need it again.

Comment: You have a git log, so it is absurd to say "thus no version history".  Classic changelogs are far less useful than a git history.

Answer (score 1):

There is no elegant way to work around the chicken-and-egg issues. As a not very elegant one you can amend your commits. So, the following sequence might work for you:

```
git commit .... -m your-message
git log > commit_log.rtf
git commit --amend -a -C HEAD
```

It will replace the last commit with the new one which will contain the same log as the last one. The only issue will be that the sha1 commit code in the log will be different from the new one.

Comment: Ah, that's pretty much I was trying to avoid. Guess I'll have to deal with it and manually change the file contents when I push to master. From torek's suggestion, I'll probably just remote into the file directory of the master and generate the log locally. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: You will still have only a single commit in the history with amend. I thought you wanted to avoid 2 commits in the history (not necessarily 2 commit commands). But in your, since the file is generated, you do not need to have it in the repository at all, as @torek suggested.